# How to apply Sigmoid on MLMultiarray elements?

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, coreml

for a torch tensor in python I can use 
`y = x[i].sigmoid()`

how do I replicate this using MLMultiArray in Swift ? 
I can get the array by `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation.featureValue.multiArrayValue` 
now I want to apply sigmoid on this

the sigmoid function I'm using is:

```
func sigmoid(z: Double) -> Double {
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-z))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typed this from memory, so there may be mistakes, but basically you grab a pointer to the memory and then loop through it:

```
let ptr = multiArray.dataPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: Double.self)
for i in 0..<multiArray.count {
  ptr[i] = sigmoid(ptr[i])
}
```

However, it's much simpler to add the sigmoid operation to the Core ML model itself and let Core ML worry about it. You can do this by adding the sigmoid operation to the original model before you convert it, or afterwards (see my book Core ML Survival Guide for instructions on how to do this).

Comment: that worked but I'm having a tough time manipulating MLMultiArrays. I'm trying to infer from a yolov5 coreml model which outputs 3 multiArrays. I've identified that I need to translate from python to swift like mentioned  [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/343#issuecomment-658021043), 
but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Can you help me here in any way ?

Comment: That's the sort of thing people pay me to do. ;-) But if you read my book, you should already be well on your way.

Comment: Ah, I see. As much as I've been frustrated with it, I really want to crack this one myself now. Thanks for your help and the book !

Comment: In case you hadn't seen it yet, [this repo](https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph) shows how to decode the predictions from YOLOv2. The approach for YOLOv5 is similar, except that you have multiple output grids instead of just one, and the math is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this function, but I think that it can achieve what you want

```
public func sigmoid_multiarray(inputs: [MLMultiArray], outputs: [MLMultiArray]) {
for i in 0..<inputs.count {
    let input=inputs[i]
    let output=outputs[i]
    
    let count = input.count
    let iptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(OpaquePointer(input.dataPointer))
    let optr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(OpaquePointer(output.dataPointer))
    
    // output = -input
    vDSP_vneg(iptr, 1, optr, 1, vDSP_Length(count))

    // output = exp(-input)
    var countAsInt32 = Int32(count)
    vvexpf(optr, optr, &countAsInt32)

    // output = 1 + exp(-input)
    var one: Float = 1
    vDSP_vsadd(optr, 1, &one, optr, 1, vDSP_Length(count))
    
    // output = 1 / 1 + exp(-input)
    var one_ar = [Float] (repeating: 1, count: input.count)
    vvdivf(optr, &one_ar, optr, &countAsInt32)
}
```

}